# Selected value not being set via jQuery / CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

```
  if addr.types[0] is "country"
    console.log addr.long_name.trim().toUpperCase()
    $("#user_country_id").each ->
      console.log $(this).text().trim()  if $(this).text().trim().toUpperCase() is addr.long_name.trim().toUpperCase()
      $(this).attr "selected", "selected"  if $(this).text().trim().toUpperCase() is addr.long_name.trim().toUpperCase()
      return
```

The code goes through a Google Places object and checks if the address component is "country", then what I want to do is update the Country select box if the TEXT matches what's returned by Google.

It's not working - just console logging the addr.long_name works and just logging the $(this).text() works (I get the whole list of countries of course...) and as far as I can tell they match.

This is the current state of the code.  I've clearly tried trim() and toUpperCase() thinking perhaps there is some sort of mismatch there - but nothing has changed.

This is written in CoffeeScript, we're just accessing some of our elements with our typical jQuery accessors.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you also share the HTML? Is `#user_country_id` the `select`? It's hard to determine what you're trying to change to "selected"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use .prop instead of .attr. For instance, selected is a property of a select box, not an attribute. So it is semantically correct, and behaves better as well.